# Django HttpResponsePermanentRedirect don't process my view

Tags: django

If I put this in my view:

```
if slug == 'old-path':
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('new-path')
```

it skips my slugbased view and returns 404.
How do I easily return 301 and "reprocess" my view so I don't get a 404?

**EDIT**
@Pydev UAs comment was the correct answer in this case, but I appreciated the detailed answer by John Debs, which gave me the hint to look into named urls, which I didn't know about. Thanks all.

Comment: That looks like you're redirecting to the wrong place. What details does the 404 error page give you? (You'll need to have `DEBUG = True` in your `settings.py` file to see this).

Comment: does 'new-path' is a valid path ? may be you passing slug instead of a path with slug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse` to your list of imports and then try this bit of code:

```
if slug == 'old-path':
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(reverse('new-path'))
```

The problem you had was that `HttpResponsePermanentRedirect()` needs a path but you were providing it with a slug.

`reverse()` will search through your [named URLs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id2) for the string you provide and return a path, which can then be redirected to properly.